# Fetching the value from db table as per user id

Tags: php, mysql

I like to fetch the value from User_book1, User_book2, User_book3 inside the db table as per User id and echoing it to my webpage. My goal is, once the Users logged-in to my webpage, display will be different defends on the user id.

Here is my sample db looks like:

```
id   |   User_name   |   User_book1   |   User_book2   |   User_book3
001  |   User A      |   visible      |   visible      |   visible
002  |   User B      |   visible      |   visible      |   none
003  |   User C      |   visible      |   none         |   none
```

here is my current query:

```
<?php
    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM users") or die("Error fetching data...");
            while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    ?>

<?php echo'<div class="col-md-4" style="display: '.$rs['User_book1'].'">'; ?> 
<?php echo'<div class="col-md-4" style="display: '.$rs['User_book2'].'">'; ?> 
<?php echo'<div class="col-md-4" style="display: '.$rs['User_book3'].'">'; ?>
```

e.g.

```
Logged-in User A --> displayed --> book1, book2, book3
Logged-in User B --> displayed --> book1, book2
Logged-in User C --> displayed --> book1
```

Problem in this query; every time the User B or User C is logged-in the displayed books is for the User A.

I am thinking to change my query codes and put the user ID:

```
<?php
    $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = '$id'") or die("Error fetching data...");
        while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
 ?>
```

but the output was Undefined variable: id. Guys help me the right query for this problem.

is there any possible way to change my current query to achieve my goal to fetch the value from User_books in db users as per id?

For additional reference here is my login session:

```
    <?php
    require('db.php');
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['User_name'])){
    $User_name = stripslashes($_REQUEST['User_name']);
    $User_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$User_name);
    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE User_name='$User_name'
    and password='".md5($password)."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1){
    $_SESSION['User_name'] = $User_name;
     header("Location: pages/home-profile.php");
         }else{
    echo "<div class='form'>
    <h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3>;
    }
      }else{
    ?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223487/discussion-on-question-by-mr-yoso-fetching-the-value-from-db-table-as-per-user-i).

Answer (score -1):

Login Session:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rows==1){
$_SESSION['User_name'] = $User_name;
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
 header("Location: pages/home-profile.php");
```

query now:

```
        $id = 0;
        if(!empty($_SESSION['id'])) {
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];
      }
            
        $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$id'") or die("Error fetching data...");
            while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
```